# Modifying Revit Family Parameters via Web Browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-data-management

My goal is to allow a user to control/edit some revit family parameters via a web browser. One one side is an input field where they can edit a parameter value. On the other side is the forge viewer which updates once they change a value from the default when the page is loaded.

Based on my review this does not seem possible.

Sources:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/globals/PropertyDatabase/ - this is read only
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ModelBuilder/ allows you to add / remove a mesh, but I don't think you can modify family type or instance parameters, like how you do in Revit family.

I am looking for:

1. Confirmation that the above goal is not possible
2. Alternative options if not possible
3. Feature request in the API so that it is possible

Answer (score 1):

The Forge viewer is a viewer and hence read-only. The Revit family is a so-called seed CAD file. It is translated into the Forge format for viewing, sharing and analysis. In that process, the amount and complexity of data is vastly reduced, so that the viewer can be able to handle models from all kinds of different CAD model editing software. In order to edit the seed CAD file from the viewer, you need to implement some kind of communication channel transferring the required model modifications from the Forge viewer back into the CAD model editing context. Once you do that, you have completed a round-trip editing flow such as you request. I implemented a whole little suite of samples connecting the desktop and the cloud, some of which are discussed in the [FireRatingCloud documentation](https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud).

Comment: Since there is no way to change the BIM family type or instance parameters through the Forge Viewer. It needs to be done via Revit and then uploaded to Forge Viewer, may be as a new revision. Could this be a feature request to have the capability to do this?

Comment: That does not make much sense, since it would be very Revit specific. Forge is a totally generic and CAD-modelling-software-agnostic tool. You cannot implement Revit-specific features in Forge.